# Create a variable in jquery with html content

Tags: jquery, html, var

Hi I am trying to create a variable in jquery that contains a table for outputting in different areas of a website. But it is giving me an error, and I do not understand why. Here is my JQUERY:

```
var copy = "<table width='750' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>Tarifa valida desde:</td>
    <td>Tarifa valida hasta:</td>
    <td>Tarifa MXN</td>
    <td>Tarifa USD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='from1' id='from1' class='date' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='to1' id='to1' class='date' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='mxn1' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='usd1' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Extra Pax MXN:</td>
    <td>Extra Pax USD:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='exmxn1' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='exusd1' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>";
    });
```

How could I place this in a variable so that I can output in various divs as so:

```
$(".divExample").html(copy);
```

Thank you in advance for anyones help!

Comment: The answers below are correct, though I would suggest a different strategy altogether. One that uses less HTML inside your JS.

Comment: The title should be "Create a variable with multiple lines"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error due to wrongly assigned string.

concatenate the lines

```
var copy = "<table width='750' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" 
            + "<tr>";
  ....
```

Answer (score 4):

You could concatenate strings like it was suggested. Or another way is to escape new line characters with back slash:

```
var html = "<table> \
    <tr>....</tr> \
    </table>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't handled the line returns in your string.  Because of this, javascript assumes that the end of each line is the end of a statement.  Clearly each line is not a valid statement.  Concatenate your string like so:

```
var "multi-"+
    "line "+
    "string";
```

Answer (score 2):

When I have complex html this is what I do. I put the html in an enclosing `DIV` and get the html content

```
var copy = $('#mycomplexhtml').html(); //gets the content I placed in an hidden div


<!-- I normally place this at the bottom-most part of the page -->
<div id="mycomplexhtml" style="display:none">
  <table width='750' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>Tarifa valida desde:</td>
    <td>Tarifa valida hasta:</td>
    <td>Tarifa MXN</td>
    <td>Tarifa USD</td>
  </tr>
 ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very clever. I have been using an html string approach, where basically I create a `var html_str = <h1>My HTML</h1>` and then add to it, line by line as, `html_str += <p>This will show beneath my H1!</p>`. However this takes a **long time** to write out, and isn't so easy to read later (even though I indent it to mimic the HTML formatting)..ugh...Going to give your method a go here, maybe some may frown on sticking hidden divs in the bottom of the HTML, but in some ways, maybe it's better than crammed into a JS file as a bunch of concatenated strings...Thanks for this clever idea..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this tool http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

It works fine :)