# How can I get original condition after clicking in a specific letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });
  $('div').click(function() {
    $('span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute"
      });
      $(this).animate({
        left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
        top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Stack Overflow</div>
```

If you click the word, the letters should all get a random position. Now: If you click any of the letters, it should look like before. So it should work like a toggle function.

Comment: Is this a bad answer? location.reload();

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Unfortunately, yes. Not the whole page should be refreshed.

Comment: Can you use a second html div element?  Or, only use the one?  Can you use z-index in your CSS?  What about .show() and .hide() ?  Can you use .html() and a variable like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333002/create-a-variable-in-jquery-with-html-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a flag to check if need to random chars, and then reset position to relative, left & top to 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isRandom = false;
  $('div').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });
  $('div').click(function() {
    isRandom = !isRandom;
    if(isRandom) {
    $('span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute"
      });
      $(this).animate({
        left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
        top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
      });
    });
    } else {
     $('span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "relative"
      });
      $(this).animate({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      });
    });
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Stack Overflow</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just wrote a new question, based on that. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335809/jquery-nesting-letter-transform-function – I would be very thankful if you could help me with that as well!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to remove `css` which is added to span using  `$(this).find("span").css({ "left": "",..})` and add some class to identify current state of text.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });

  $('div').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("already")) {
      //remove css added to span
      $(this).find("span").css({
        "left": "",
        "top": "",
        "position": ""
      });
      //remove already class
      $(this).removeClass("already")
    } else {
      //add class to identify 
      $(this).addClass("already")
      $('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "position": "absolute"
        });
        $(this).animate({
          left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
          top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
        });
      });

    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Stack Overflow</div>
```