# jQuery: Nesting letter transform function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isRandom = false;
  $('#one, #two').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });
  $('#one').click(function() {
    isRandom = !isRandom;
    if (isRandom) {
      $('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "position": "absolute"
        });
        $(this).animate({
          left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
          top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
        });
      });
    } else {
      $('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "position": "relative"
        });
        $(this).animate({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one">Click me</div>
<div id="two">Flying letters based on #one</div>
<div>No flying letters</div>
```

If you click the first `div`, the letters from `#one` and `#two` start moving. That's exactly how it should look like. **But then:** If you want to get the previous state, you would need have to click a letter from `#once`. It also should work if you click one of the two other `div`.

How is it possible to do that? Would be happy if somebody could help me!

Comment: Maybe `$('#one').click(` can be `$('#one #two').click(`

Comment: Set left and top to 0 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your selector to some class which is same to all divs then inside event handler you just need to check if the div which is clicked has `id` has `one` using `&&` if yes then only `if` part will get executed .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isRandom = false;
  $('#one, #two').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });
  //chnage slector
  $('div.sameclass').click(function() {
    isRandom = !isRandom;
    //check if the div which is clicked has id one..
    if (isRandom && $(this).attr("id") == "one") {
      $('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "position": "absolute"
        });
        $(this).animate({
          left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
          top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
        });
      });
    } else {
      $('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "position": "relative"
        });
        $(this).animate({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one" class="sameclass">Click me</div>
<div id="two" class="sameclass">Flying letters based on #one</div>
<div class="sameclass">No flying letters</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `click` event on `#two` to do that as below -

```
$('#two').click(function() {
if (isRandom) {
  isRandom = false;
  $('span').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "position": "relative"
    });
    $(this).animate({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
    });
  });
}
});
```

Final code (I have extracted into functions for better understanding) -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isRandom = false;
  $('#one, #two').html(function(i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  });

  $('#one').click(function() {
    isRandom = !isRandom;
    if (isRandom) {
      fly();
    } else {
      restore();
    }
  });

  $('#two').click(function() {
    if (isRandom) {
      isRandom = false;
      restore();
    }
  });

  function fly() {
    $('span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute"
      });
      $(this).animate({
        left: Math.random() * window.outerWidth / 2,
        top: Math.random() * window.outerHeight / 2,
      });
    });
  }

  function restore() {
    $('span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "relative"
      });
      $(this).animate({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one">Click me</div>
<div id="two">Flying letters based on #one</div>
<div>No flying letters</div>
```